# Can't ignore /.angular/cache in new Angular 13 project

Tags: angular, angular13

I created a project from scratch that uses Angular 13. I can't seem to be able to get the angular cache to be ignored so that these files won't be included in source control.

I've tried adding all the following to .gitnore `.angular, /.angular/cache, .angular/cache, *.angular/cache` but none of these worked. When I run npm start, I still get the cache changes getting tracked.

This is how my file directory structure looks like

[image]

This is output from npm start:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your cache files were already added in a previous commit. The changelog in your VSCode screenshot shows that the committed cached files are being removed (hence the red `D` on the right).

Here are two options for you:

1. Commit these changes as is, and the files will be removed and untracked from the repo (but they'll still be in your commit history when they were added).
2. Undo the commit where these files were added. Then update your .gitignore where you only add the `.angular` directory.

Comment: This was 100% it. Since it was a brand new project, I was convinced I hadn't done any commits. That's what I get for working tired and doing zombie commits. Hopefully, it helps others who do the same silly mistake and come on here to look for the answer.